# Poynting vector and negative index of refraction

Tags: optics, refraction, poynting-vector, metamaterials

Why are the Poynting vector and the wavevector not pointing in the same direction in negative-index media?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually they are, since a negative index only means that the propagation is reversed. As $n$ changes sign, so are the magnetic field and Poynting vector, ans so does the wavevector. Unless you're talking about another situation, in which case your question lacks clarity.